# Node js выводить undefind вместо html шаблона

Tags: node.js

Есть такой код. Смысл, всего взять инфу с json файла и заменить в шаблоне html.
что-то типа шаблонизатора, подставить инфу. Нов консоле выводить undefind

***Пример json:***

```
[
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
      "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    },
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 2,
      "title": "qui est esse",
      "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
    }
```

таких итемов больше 100

```js
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const fs = require('fs');

//main functions
const replaceTemplate = (temp, post)=>{
    let output = temp.replace(/{%POSTTILE%}/g, post.title);
    output = output.replace(/{%POSTBODY%}/g, post.body);
    output = output.replace(/{%POSTID%}/g, post.id);
}

const posts = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/data/posts.json`, 'utf-8');
const comments = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/data/comments.json`, 'utf-8');

const dataPosts =  JSON.parse(posts);
const dataComments = JSON.parse(comments);

//templates
const template_posts = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/templates/posts.html`, 'utf-8');
const template_comments = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/templates/post_detail.html`, 'utf-8');

//logic
const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.url);
    const pathName =  req.url;
    
    if (pathName === '/'){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/html'});
        const postsHTML = dataPosts.map(el => replaceTemplate(template_posts, el));
        console.log(postsHTML);
        
        
        res.end(template_posts);
    }
    else if (pathName === '/post'){
        res.end('Post detail');
    }
    else{
        res.writeHead(404, {
            'Content-type':'text/html',
            'my-own-header':'some header'
        });
        res.end('<h1>Page not found 404</h1>');
    }
});


server.listen(8000, 'localhost', ()=>{
    console.log("Server On!");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <h1>All Posts</h1>
        <tr>
            <td><a href='/post?id={%POST_ID%}'>{%POST_TITLE%}</a></td>
            <td>{%POST_BODY%}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А возвращать output кто будет?

Comment: @Alexey Ten не совсем понятен ваш ответ. Речь идет о консоле и по идее в нее должен выводиться html  шаблона с измененными значениями заглушки.

Comment: Ваша функция replace_template ничего не возвращает

Comment: @Alexey Ten  спасибо, возвращает, но не заменяет заглушки в шаблоне

Comment: Ну так у вас в шаблоне и replace написаны разные строки. Вообще такие глупые ошибки надо уметь находить самостоятельно.